# The second thread in my program is not being executed

Tags: python, multithreading

I am a beginner in python. I learnt and applied Multi-threading in program but only one thread is being executed.

The program is about calling function which returns the distance value using Ultrasonic sensor and saving the frames of video from webcam with time stamps. I have tried the code without threading and it works fine but the number of frames are reduced due to time taken in distance measurement so I thought to execute them in parallel using Multi-threading in python.

```
import threading
import thread
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
class u1Thread(threading.Thread):
      def run(self): 
         TRIG1=23                            #Associate pin 23 to TRIG
         ECHO1=24                            #Associate pin 24 to ECHO
         GPIO.setup(TRIG1,GPIO.OUT)          #Set pin as GPIO out
         GPIO.setup(ECHO1,GPIO.IN)           #Set pin as GPIO in
         U_1=[]
         start=[]
         while True:
            d=ultrasonic(TRIG1,ECHO1)
            U_1.append(d)
            start.append(str(time.time()))
            x=pd.DataFrame({'1st':U_1,  'Time Stamp':start})
            export_csv = x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/q.csv', index = None, 
            header=True)


 class vfThread(threading.Thread):
       def run(self):
       ret, frame=video.read()
       if ret == True:  
          cv2.imwrite(str(time.time()) + '.jpg',frame)   


U1=u1Thread()
VF=vfThread()


U1.run()
VF.run()
```

I was expecting both threads to be executed but only first is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `U1.start()` and `VF.start()` instead of `run`.

`run` executes the code without starting a new thread, thus, the program get stuck in the `while` loop.

`start` starts a thread and execute `run` inside it. Both threads runs at the same time.

Comment: The problem is not resolved yet. Like for 100 sensor values of 1st thread only 1 frame of second thread is saved.                                     I need parallel processing. Please suggest.

Comment: @Bilal It means that the second thread is now running in parallel. So this part of the problem (the one asked in the question) is resolved. Now you seem to have another problem.

Comment: @Bilal You second problem is that the second thread is reading a frame, writes it, then stops the thread. You need a loop to perform many write operations.

Comment: Just asking can I define six more threads as class in this multi threading program ?

Comment: @Bilal Theoretically, there is no limit on the number of threads you can create. In practice, it depends on the available memory, the number of handles an OS can allocate, etc. For most programs, it is never a problem. In the end, it depends on the complexity of managing many threads. If they all need to talk to each other, the complexity of managing the threads will increase.